# Threshold Energy for Creation of Electron-Positron Pair from Collision of Electron Pair

Tags: special-relativity, nuclear-physics, collision

In short:
$$
e^{-}+e^{-} \rightarrow e^{-}+e^{-}+\left(e^{-}+e^{+}\right)
$$

My professor discussed this example in class in a Special Relativity Lecture. He used conservation of four vector momentum.

$$
\mathbf{P}_1+\mathbf{P}_2=\mathbf{P}_3+\mathbf{P}_4+\mathbf{P}_5+\mathbf{P}_6
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \left(\mathbf{P}_1+\mathbf{P}_2\right)^2=\left(\mathbf{P}_3+\mathbf{P}_4+\mathbf{P}_5+\mathbf{P}_6\right)^2 \\
& \mathbf{P}_1=\left\{\vec{p}_1, i \frac{E_1}{c}\right\} \quad \mathbf{P}_2=\left\{0, i m_0 c\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

However, I am not able to agree with the statement that at threshold energy all the particles produced are at rest.

$$
\left(\mathbf{P}_3+\mathbf{P}_4+\mathbf{P}_5+\mathbf{P}_6\right)^2=\left\{\vec{p}_3+\vec{p}_4+\vec{p}_5+\vec{p}_6, 4 i m_0 c\right\}^2
$$

He then further went on say that sum of the momentum of the particles produced was zero. But wouldn't this violate the conservation of spatial momentum?

Comment: You skipped your instructor's crucial qualification; he *must have said*: "***in the center-of-momentum frame***" as well!

Comment: I see, but if we observed the momentum in the COM frame of the reaction products how would it gaurantee that one of the electrons between the reactants would be stationary in the COM frame of the products ? Or do we just assume that it has the exact velocity as COM frame to simply things?

Comment: Threshold is the lower bound, so, by definition, vanishing kinetic energy of the products in the COM. Above that energy, all products have some momentum, of course.

Answer (score -1):

$$p_1^{\mu}=(E, p)$$
$$p_2^{\mu}=(E,-p)$$

With

$$E = 2m_e$$

Gives

$$p_i^{\mu} = (4m_e, 0)$$

Then the final 4 momenta are all:

$$ p^{\mu}=(m_e, 0) $$